# on click Cell bold EventHandler

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

This is my first post so still learning on our to use stack overflow, so please be kind haha.

The following scripts adds a row using insert alerts..( I know annoying) Im trying to have javascript start an event handler, to BOLD individual cells that the user clicks on, never used event handler's before, i know how to bold it but i simply bold the newly added rows.. not the individual cell...... any advice on this would help, also i hope the formatting of this post is not to annoying.

Below is the code with in-line javascript.

```html
<html>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
          <title>Address Book</title>
          <style type="text/css">
              .ab {
         font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: small;
         color: #993300;
         background-color: #CCFFCC;
         padding: 5px;
         height: 100px;
         width: 350px;
         border: thin dotted #993300;
            }
          </style>
          
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function addressBookItem (fname, lname, email) {
                this.fname= fname;
                this.lname = lname; 
                this.email = email;
            }
         
         addressBookItem.prototype.write = function() {
                var adrbook = "<tr><td>"+this.fname+"</td><td>"+this.lname+"</td><td>"+this.email+"</td></tr>";

                document.write(adrbook);
            }

            function appendRow(){
              var fname = prompt("Please enter your first name");
              var lname = prompt("Please enter your last name");
              var email = prompt("Please enter your email");
            
           
              var table = document.getElementById("nameT");

              // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
              var row = table.insertRow(-1);

              // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

              // Add some text to the new cells:
              cell1.innerHTML = fname;
              cell2.innerHTML = lname;
              cell3.innerHTML = email;
              //row.style.color="red";
              cell.onclick = function () { alert(this.innerHTML); };
              
            }


            function yourFunction(){
                       alert("test");
                    }
         
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table border="1" id="nameT">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                var aB1 = new addressBookItem('Roger', 'Williams', 'rwilliams@gmail.com');
                var aB2 = new addressBookItem ('Rose', 'Schultz', 'rose_s@earthlink.net');
                aB1.write();
                aB2.write();
        </script> 
        </table>
        <button onclick="appendRow()">new</button>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You're never setting the variable `cell`.

Comment: I don't see where in your code you're making anything bold.

Comment: yea it simply is just just being added at the bottom, i have no idea how to dynamically add an id/variable to a cell. that has been added by the above method..but its the only method that was working when i tried.


Yea i took out the event handler for the bold because it was bolding the whole row.. i can show the function if you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding the new cells, add an event listener to them that sets its style.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Address Book</title>
  <style type="text/css">
      .ab {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: small;
 color: #993300;
 background-color: #CCFFCC;
 padding: 5px;
 height: 100px;
 width: 350px;
 border: thin dotted #993300;
    }
  </style>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
function addressBookItem (fname, lname, email) {
    this.fname= fname;
    this.lname = lname; 
    this.email = email;
}

addressBookItem.prototype.write = function() {
    var adrbook = "<tr><td>"+this.fname+"</td><td>"+this.lname+"</td><td>"+this.email+"</td></tr>";

    document.write(adrbook);
}

function appendRow(){
    var fname = prompt("Please enter your first name");
    var lname = prompt("Please enter your last name");
    var email = prompt("Please enter your email");


    var table = document.getElementById("nameT");

    // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);

    // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

    // Add some text to the new cells:
    cell1.innerHTML = fname;
    cell2.innerHTML = lname;
    cell3.innerHTML = email;
    var cells = [cell1, cell2, cell3];
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (this.style.fontWeight == "bold") {
                this.style.fontWeight = "normal";
            } else {
                this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
            }
        });
    }
}


function yourFunction(){
    alert("test");
}
         
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" id="nameT">
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var aB1 = new addressBookItem('Roger', 'Williams', 'rwilliams@gmail.com');
        var aB2 = new addressBookItem ('Rose', 'Schultz', 'rose_s@earthlink.net');
        aB1.write();
        aB2.write();
</script> 
</table>
<button onclick="appendRow()">new</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i didn't think of using the (i = 0; i < length; i++) method, but this has been extremely helpful thank you.. I get stuck on the simplest of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to The StackOverflow,

All you need to do to make cell's text bold on click is simply add these three event listeners and then setting their innerHTML to bold:

```
           cell1.onclick = function () {
              if(this.innerHTML[0] !== "<")
                  this.innerHTML = "<b>"+this.innerHTML+"</b>";
              else
                  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.substr(3,this.innerHTML.length-3);
              };
          cell2.onclick = function () {   
              if(this.innerHTML[0] !== "<")
                  this.innerHTML = "<b>"+this.innerHTML+"</b>";
              else
                  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.substr(3,this.innerHTML.length-3);
              };
          cell3.onclick = function () {   
              if(this.innerHTML[0] !== "<")
                  this.innerHTML = "<b>"+this.innerHTML+"</b>";
              else
                  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.substr(3,this.innerHTML.length-3);
              };
```

Remember, there can be more efficient ways of doing this but for the sake of simplicity and beginner's understanding, you should get it quite easily. The more you practice and learn Javascript/HTML/CSS, the better you'll get.

*EDIT:* Added the bold/unbold on clicks.

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6u8wfocb/1/)**

Comment: Hate to be a complete newbie haha, but could you possible add an 

IF (Bold){ unbold}
ELSE IF (NotBold){bold}

Comment: The 90's called, they want their archaic style markup back. Use CSS.

Comment: don't worry, i'm being a total beginner at it as well, check my updated answer.. @Barmar let him learn it the hard way (:

Comment: Farout, i was attempting to do it a completely different way, but what your doing is kind of trimming the "<br>" + "</br>" using the substring wouldn't this pick up the BR tags ?  

or am i 100% wrong hahah

Comment: what its doing is if cell's text doesnt start with '<' (very inefficient way, mind you), it will put the text in <b> tags which will make it bold.. else means text is already bold, so it's trimming <b> tags which will only left the unbold text.

Comment: "<b> some text </b>" will appear bold.. else.. "some text" will appear normal

Comment: Thank you, these answers have been quite helpful. and it was the removing of the B tags which was fairly difficult, but i seem to understand your method, will take me a while to implement myself but its a great reference.

Comment: You're welcome.. and as i said the more you practice, the better you'll get